# Need Help to set up Package that contains Foreach Loop container SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am new with SSIS packages, There is a specific process I want to accomplish.

1st) I want to get a record set from a SQL Server DB and Mark that I have retrieved the specific rows.

2nd) Loop through each row

3rd) for each row looped through call a web service and pass two fields to the web service as input parameters.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step to do this is to create a few SSIS variables.  Select View > Other Windows > Variables to display the variables window.  Add a variable that will contain your result set from the SQL query.  Set the data type to Object.  Create additional variables for each column selected in the query.

In the Connection Managers tab, add a new Connection Manger.  Edit and configure the new Connection Manager with the SQL Server connection information (e.g., Server name, authentication and database, etc.)

Add an Execute SQL Task to the Control Flow.  Edit the task. In the Connection property, select your new Connection Manager.  Enter the SQL SELECT statement in the SQLStatement property. Set the ResultSet property to Full result set.

Select the Result Set tab in the Execute SQL Task.  Add a new result set.  Set the Result Name to 0 and the Variable Name to the object variable you created earlier.  Close the editor.

Add a Foreach Loop Container to Control Flow.  Create a Precedence Constraint (green line) from the Execute SQL Task to the Foreach Loop Container.  This will ensure that the SQL task must succeed before the Foreach Loop starts.

Edit the Forach Loop Container and select the Collection tab.  Set the Enumerator property to Foreach ADO Enumerator and select your object variable in the ADO object source variable.  Select the Variable Mappings tab.  Select your variables that will retrieve the column value for each row.  Associate the first variable with the first column by selecting index 0.  Index 1 will be the second column, etc.

Add a Web Service Task in the Foreach Loop Container.  This task will run once for each row in the result set.  You can use the variable values to configure the Web Service Task.  You may need to work with expressions if the property doesn't directly accept variables.

If you want to mark your rows one at a time, you can add another Execute SQL Task and place it into the Foreach Loop Container.  Configure it similarly to the first Execute SQL Task, but create an SQL UPDATE statement.  You might consider updating all rows the rows at once to get better performance.  If so, then move the Execute SQL Task out of the Foreach Loop Container and configure the UPDATE statement so that it updates the set of rows.

Comment: Thanks for the walk through! I have followed it except for the first part of Execute SQL task. I changed it to call a procedure on the database. the procedure updates the records as completed and returns a recordset of the updated records. I use the follwing setting: ConnectionType "ADO SQLSourceType "Direct input",

Comment: Is there a way to execute something extra only if the webservice call fails?

Comment: Yes.  You can create multiple precedence constraints that exit the Web Service task.  The precedence constraint default setting indicates to go to the next task if the previous task succeeded.  You can change this setting to go to next task if the previous task failed.  So, your green line from the Web Service indicates the success path.  Add another precedence constraint from the Web Service to the "execute something extra" task for the failed path.  Edit the precedence constraint (rt. click the line and select Edit).  Change the Constraint Options Value from Success to Failure.